# Sourcing bash file inside PyQt4 GUI

Tags: bash, python-2.7, subprocess, pyqt4, ros

I'm working on a GUI built with PyQt4 and Python 2.7 that launches various demos for a [Clearpath Husky](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/husky-unmanned-ground-vehicle-robot/) running ROS Indigo. The GUI switches between [launching navigation demos](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials) and visualizing my physical robot. To do this, it has to switch between launching demos on a local ROS and the ROS on my Husky. When switching between the two different ROS instances I need to be able to "source" the devel/setup.bash for each OS so that the packages are built correctly and visualizing the Husky inside Rviz doesn't break (Errors with TF frames like "No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [odom] does not exist" and with RobotModel "URDF Model failed to parse"). In my .bashrc, if I source the Husky's setup.bash, the visualization works fine until I try running a local demo. This also happens vice versa; while sourcing the local setup.bash will run the local demos just fine, the Husky's visualization breaks.

Is there a way to use python's subprocess (or another alternative) to source the appropriate devel/setup.bash within the GUI's instance so that the visualization won't break?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, that worked great thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be sufficient to source the setup script just before executing the ROS command you want, for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

shell_setup_script = "/some/path/to/workspace/devel/setup.sh"
command = "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"
cmd = ". %s; %s" % (shell_setup_script, command)

output = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

As you see, `shell=True` is used, which will execute the `cmd` in a subshell. Then, `cmd` contains `. <shell_setup_script>; <command>` which sources the setup script before executing the command. Please note that the `.sh` file is sourced instead of `.bash` since generic POSIX shell is likely to be used by Popen.